# php preg_match between Combination of square brackets and brackets

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-split

i want to use preg_match to find text between [{}] for example: $varx = "[{xx}]";

final output will be $match = 'xx';

another example $varx = "bla bla [{yy}] bla bla";

final output will be something like this $match = 'yy';

in other words it strips out bracket. i'm still confusing with regular expression but found that sometimes preg match is more simple solution. searching other example but not meet my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work for you:

```
preg_match('/\[\{([^\]\}]+)\}\]/', $varx, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or like this

`preg_match('/(?<=\[\{).*?(?=\}\])/', $varx, $match);`

Comment: This will not work if there are more than 1 `[{yy}]` in a line like `bla bla [{yy}] bla bla bla bla [{yy}] bla bla`

Comment: Thank you very much you are right. I edited my answer now it will work

Answer (score 1):

Both kinds of brackets are [meta-characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in `regex`. If you want to match them you have to [escape them](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) (escaping the opening brackets is enough):

```
$varx = "bla bla [{yy}] bla bla";
preg_match('/\[\{([^\]}]*)}]/', $varx, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It displays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{yy}]
    [1] => yy
)
```

The `regex`:

```
/           # delimiter; it is not part of the regex but separates it 
            #      from the modifiers (no modifiers are used in this example);
\[          # escaped '[' to match literal '[' and not use its special meaning
\{          # escaped '{' to match literal '{' and not use its special meaning
(           # start of a group (special meaning of '(' when not escaped)
   [^       # character class, excluding (special meaning of '[' when not escaped)
        \]  # escaped ']' to match literal ']' (otherwise it means end of class)
        }   # literal '}'
   ]        # end of the character class
   *        # repeat the previous expression zero or more times
)           # end of group
}]          # literal '}' followed by ']'
/           # delimiter
```

**How it works:**

It matches the sequence of `[{` characters (`\[\{`) followed by zero or more (`*`) characters that are not (`^`) in the class (`[...]`), followed by `}]`. The class contains two characters (`]` and `}`) and everything between `[{` and `}]` is enclosed in a capturing group (`(...)`).

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) puts in `$matches` at index `0` the part of the string that matches the entire `regex` (`[{yy}]`) and on numeric indices starting with `1` the substrings that match each [capturing group](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php).

If the input string contains more than one `[{...}]` block you want to match then you have to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('/\[\{([^\]}]*)}]/', $varx, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

When the fourth argument is `PREG_SET_ORDER`, `$matches` contains a list of arrays as exposed above.